# Create a variable that contains the id of clicked div

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Does anybody have any idea how to create a variable that contains the id of a clicked div?

I want to hide all the #content-wrappers on page load apart from the first one then when the .square has been clicked for it to display the div with the same class as the id that has been clicked, it doesn't make much sense when you write id down but if you look at my fiddle then it should hopefully make sense?

http://jsfiddle.net/alexjamest/Lkaxza22/

```
$('#content-wrapper').hide();

$(".square").click(function() {
var id_name= $(this).attr(id);
if $('#content-wrapper').hasClass(id_name){
 $(this).fadeIn();   
}
}); 


<div id="content-wrapper" class="c1">Content 1</div>
<div id="content-wrapper" class="c2">Content 2</div>
<div id="content-wrapper" class="c3">Content 3</div>
<div id="content-wrapper" class="c4">Content 4</div>
<div id="content-wrapper" class="c5">Content 5</div>
<div id="content-wrapper" class="c6">Content 6</div>
<div id="content-wrapper" class="c7">Content 7</div>
<div id="content-wrapper" class="c8">Content 8</div>

<div class="square" id="c1"></div>
<div class="square" id="c2"></div>
<div class="square" id="c3"></div>
<div class="square" id="c4"></div>
<div class="square" id="c5"></div>
<div class="square" id="c6"></div>
<div class="square" id="c7"></div>
<div class="square" id="c8"></div>
```

Comment: You should not use same id for multiple elements

Comment: @dreyescat No, he is getting id of square div and applying id's class to wrapper...

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal I mean `id="content-wrapper"`

Comment: Oh! I didn't see that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four problems with your code:

1. `$('#content-wrapper').hide();` will only hide the first element with that ID, because IDs have to be unique. Use a common class instead.
2. `var id_name= $(this).attr(id);`. `id` is an undefined variable. You probably want to pass the string `"id"` instead, or better, just access the property of the DOM element: `this.id`.
3. `if $('#content-wrapper').hasClass(id_name){` is a syntax error. The condition has to be put in parhenthesis:

   ```
   if ($('#content-wrapper').hasClass(id_name)) {
   ```
4. However, that alone won't make the condition work, since again, `#content-wrapper` will only select the first element. Just select the corresponding element by class:

   ```
    $('.' + this.id).fadeIn();
   ```

   You can also add `.content-wrapper` for more granular filtering:

   ```
    $('.content-wrapper.' + this.id).fadeIn();
   ```

Fixed code:

```
$('.content-wrapper').hide(); // give that class to all elements instead of the ID

$(".square").click(function() {
   $('.' + this.id).fadeIn();  
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkaxza22/2/)

Comment: Thanks for this, how would i get the previous content-wrapper to fade out when another square has been clicked?

Comment: You could simply fade out all of them and then fade in the new one. Or you could use the `:visible` selector to only fadeOut the currently visible content, in which case you can do that in parallel: `$('.content-wrapper:visible').fadeOut();  $('.' + this.id).fadeIn();`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `content-wrapper`s elements so that they contain classes, not ids, since **ids should be unique**. You can, however, identify your content with some sort of a prefix, like `content-`:

```
<div class="content-wrapper" id="content-c1">Content 1</div>
<div class="content-wrapper" id="content-c2">Content 2</div>
<div class="content-wrapper" id="content-c3">Content 3</div>
<div class="content-wrapper" id="content-c4">Content 4</div>
<div class="content-wrapper" id="content-c5">Content 5</div>
<div class="content-wrapper" id="content-c6">Content 6</div>
<div class="content-wrapper" id="content-c7">Content 7</div>
<div class="content-wrapper" id="content-c8">Content 8</div>
```

Then the following code will work:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        $(".content-wrapper").hide();
        $(document).on("click", ".square", function()
        {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $("#content-"+id).fadeIn();   
        });
});
```

Note the following part

```
$(".content-wrapper").hide();
```

which is important, since we're identifying that we wish to hide all elements which contain the **class** `content-wrapper`, not the **id** `content-wrapper`.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z9L1v65e/5/).

Comment: You should really explain what you changed and why.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal: No, it's not `attr(id) -> attr("id")`

Comment: Without explanation, that was mystery.

Comment: *"Unfortunetly, you're not displaying those elements visually since they contain nothing."* Did you look at their demo? I can see lots of squares.

Comment: @FelixKling The squares you see are the ones with id="content-wrapper". Check my new demo, it works perfectly.

Comment: I assure you they are not. Scroll down: http://jsfiddle.net/alexjamest/Lkaxza22/. Check my demo, it works perfectly too.

Comment: @FelixKling "<div class="square" id="c8"></div>" The .square elements contain the empty string.

Comment: I don't deny that. But the CSS that is applied to them gives them a width and height: `.square{ width: 100px; height: 100px; }`.

Comment: *"The source of your problem is that you're listening to clicks on elements which have the square class. "* That's not the source at all. Why should it be?

Comment: @FelixKling Because he never clicks on the .square elements, he clicks on the content-wrappers. If he properly changes the ids to classes, hides the elements which contain those classes, adds some text to the .square elements then he can listen to _them_.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lkaxza22/2/ hopefully convinces you that binding the event handler, or the way the `.square` elements are defined, is not the problem. DOM elements don't need content to be able to bind an event handler to them.

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry, I did not notice the css part, or read the comments properly, which made the squares visible. I removed the incorrect part and made the squares visible in my demo. In my defense, I'm tired :)

Answer (score 0):

A JQuery-less solution, still with the fade animation.

On load it gets an array of buttons and an array of content wrappers, then it just uses the order to figure out which box to reveal. Will only work with an equal number of buttons and wrappers. I started the wrappers as invisible in the style sheet, so we only have to reveal them. Also remembers which buttons was clicked last and resets its visibility.

```
<head>
    <style>
    .content-wrapper{
        opacity:0;
        transition:opacity 1s ease;/* only showing the normal one, prefixed may be required for portability*/
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    window.addEventListener('load',onload,false);
    var wrappers;
    var buttons;
    var last; 
    function onload(){

        wrappers = document.getElementsByClassName('content-wrapper');
        buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('square');

        var i = buttons.length;
        while(i--) // add listener for each button
            buttons[i].addEventListener('click',onclick,false);

    }
    function onclick(){
        if(last)wrappers[last].style.opacity = '0.0'; //hide previous
        var i = buttons.indexOf(this);
        wrappers[i].style.opacity = '1.0'; //show clicked
        last = i;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='content-wrapper'></div>
    <div class='content-wrapper'></div>
    <div class='content-wrapper'></div>
    <div class='content-wrapper'></div>
    <div class='content-wrapper'></div>
    <div class='square'></div>
    <div class='square'></div>
    <div class='square'></div>
    <div class='square'></div>
    <div class='square'></div>
</body>
```